# Unable to launch a webpage other than youtube app using cobalt browser

Tags: cobalt

I have followed the steps given in cobalt.googlesource.com to build the cobalt browser. It does launch Youtube app successfully. But when I try to launch a web page such as https://www.google.com, it ignores the pointed URL and always launches the Youtube app.

Launching the URL as,

out/linux-x64x11_debug/cobalt --url=https://www.google.com.

am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 1):

While you can launch other web sites, please do not expect Cobalt to render and browser them smoothly. Cobalt supports [limited sets of HTML/CSS/JS](http://cobalt.foo/development/reference/supported-features.html), so it's likely other websites use unsupported technologies.

Answer (score 0):

There is a navigation whitelist installed here:
https://cobalt.googlesource.com/cobalt/+/master/src/cobalt/browser/application.cc#458

You can disable it with the `--csp_mode=disabled` command-line flag, but that will not work on GOLD builds.

Comment: David, thanks for the response. Does it mean that the gold build is always intended to use for  YouTube app only?

Comment: Not as such, but it improves security rather significantly for any application that is blessed enough to be in the whitelist. If you want to use it for other apps, you will probably want to add the specific sites to it, until a future version where the hard-coded whitelist can be removed.